# ios: Is it possible to choose one out of two defined categories of same class at runtime

Tags: ios, categories

I have two categories defined for the same class and have same function but different definition. I want to choose a particular function of a category at runtime on some condition.
Does obj c compiler maintain some book keeping for categories.

I was thinking in terms of C++ (virtual function/Vtable) where these can be achieved using polymorphism. How can I solve such scenario in objective C.

```
Class MyClass;

File:Myclass+category1.h
@interface MyClass (CategoryOne)
-(void) printCategory()
@end 

File:Myclass+category2.h
@interface MyClass (CategoryTwo)
-(void) printCategory()
@end
```

Now I included both the header files in MyClass.m. Is there any possibility of liberty of choosing the particular definition of "printCategory()" at some runtime condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If two categories implement the same method, it is undefined which one is executed.

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1):

> There’s no limit to the number of categories that you can add to a class, but each category name must be different, and each should declare and define a different set of methods.

Comment: Thanks!! Yeah I have been going through the doc and got that as well. Excuse my laziness to begin with ;-).